# Word Interop: how to insert a citation field?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have a Selection and would like to use it to insert a citation. Currently, I insert an index mark using

```
Selection sel;
    :
string cmd = "Lincoln, Abraham";
document.Indexes.MarkEntry(sel.Range, Entry: cmd);
```

I'm thinking that inserting a citation would be similar, but am not seeing the equivalent of `Document.InsertCitation()` or `Document.Bibliography.InsertCitation()`?

Comment: Not something I work with but... Have you tried the macro recorder in order to get the basic syntax?

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks for the suggestion. That hadn't occurred to me. I ran Record Macro and the resulting Sub was empty, so this feature not programmatically available?

Comment: oh, it's almost certainly available, just not picked up by the recorder. Unfortunately, the recrder hasn't been maintained as well as developers could wish. "Old technology" - but what "they" forget is that the newer technologies would also benefit! I don't have an opportunity to check for the next couple of days. If you don't get a response try asking with the word-vba and vba tags or in a forum like Microsoft Answers, where you're more likley to find people who work with that functionality.

Comment: Please did you finally get the solution to this issue? I need to use this functionality too if it is available.

Answer (score 0):

Try TableOfAuthorities ?? That works in VBA

```
Document.TablesOfAuthorities.MarkCitation _
  Range:=Selection.Range, ShortCitation:=Selection.Range.Text, _
  LongCitation:="Michaels v. McVinney", Category:=1
```